# How to set ingestion mapping for TSV or W3CLOGFILE format in Kusto database in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: json, csv, azure-data-explorer, kql, data-mapping

I am relatively new to Kusto. I was wondering how do we specify ingestion mappings in Kusto for formats other than CSV, JSON, AVRO, ORC, or Parquet. I could see examples only for these data formats in the documentation. I want to create an ingestion mapping for TSV or W3CLOGFILE format, and ingest data through the built-in pipeline in ADX from azure blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TSV it is the same as CSV, see relevant [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#csv-mapping) comment:

> CSV mapping can be applied on all the delimiter-separated formats:
> CSV, TSV, PSV, SCSV, and SOHsv.

As for W3CLOGFILE, the mapping format is the same as for [AVRO mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#avro-mapping)